# How do I extract an image from a MEDIUMTEXT, MyISAM field?

Tags: php, mysql

My goal is to get a db dump which contains binary image data into a real image or a display of one in a web page. I have a database dump that creates and inserts data into an attachments table with an example https://gist.github.com/marr/d22b418f5744d56dcb69.

The data from a single `filedata` cell was copied into `foo.jpg` so I could run `file` on it which only lists the file as "data". EDIT: After changing the select to `SELECT BINARY filedata ...`, I was able to get the `file` command to recognize it as jpg

```
$ file foo.jpg
foo.jpg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
```

How would I script that to either output files on my filesystem or display them with php or rails...

The typical PHP doesn't work:

```
mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","");
mysql_select_db("foo");

$imageId = intval($_GET["id"]);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT BINARY filedata FROM attachment WHERE attachmentid = ". $imageId);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);

$mime = 'image/jpeg';

header("Content-Type: $mime");
header("Content-Disposition: inline");

echo $row["filedata"]; //blank
```

Comment: Use a `BLOB` or `VARBINARY` field type to store a byte array to MySQL

Comment: Your code is not checking to see if (a) the query succeeded , and (b) if it returned any rows. You are also not checking if your connection succeeded or if the database selection worked. Thus you could have had a silent failure in at least 4 places that would explain the empty result. If you want to have the code that is robust and easy to debug, make a habit of checking for errors subconsciously, like you would check the blind spot before changing lanes when driving.